# 1.5l Mitsubishi mirage manual clutch kit install...already have bell housing back on...can't remember how the routing went of components

Tags: manual-transmission, mitsubishi

You already know what type of vehicle and that this issue has to do with wiring and brackets and components placement. What I need is a view or summary with relative description as to where everything goes after the transmission is reached to the motor and the motor mounts are back in place. Please help me thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Could you please post some pictures of where you are at in the process? What have you already attached to where and detail exactly what you've done? There's about a billion (well, maybe a million) things we could describe here. I'm hopeful you can narrow down exactly where you are at and what you're stuck on.